# How do I make a powershell function return an object and set $? to $false?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have some code in a powershell function that looks like this:

```
try {
    Invoke-SomethingThatFails
}
catch [System.Exception] {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message;
    return New-Object Namespace.CustomErrorType -Property @{
        'Code' = "Fail";
        "Message" = $_.Exception.Message;
    }
}
```

Now the only problem is I'd also like to set $? to be $false. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't get what you wan't. $? is readonly and can't changed.

Comment: Well how do I indicate that the function returned in error, which would make the readonyl variable $? to be false?

Comment: Ouu now I get what you want, I have the same exact need when I create a wrapper for the Out-Default to save automaticly the last object in some variable and to respond to urls(idea taken from Powershell In Action 2). That idea was great but I screw the $? variable. The workaround that I use was to create a personalized $MyErrorIndicator variable, I don't like too much, but was the only thing that comes to my mind to keep those new functionalities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Bruce Payettes' [PowerShell In Action (Second Edition)](http://www.manning.com/payette2/):

> The $? variable will be true if the entire operation succeeded, and
>   false otherwise. For example, if any of the operations wrote an error
>   object, then $? will be set to false even if the error was discarded
>   using redirection. This is an important point: it means that a script
>   can determine whether an error occurred even if the error isn’t
>   displayed.

The PowerShell runtime manages the value of `$?` and is set to false when an error object gets written in the pipeline.

**Update** Here is how you can write an error object to the pipeline but not terminate it (the pipeline):

```
function New-Error {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    $MyErrorRecord = new-object System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord `
        "", `
        "", `
        ([System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::NotSpecified), `
        ""
    $PSCmdlet.WriteError($MyErrorRecord)
}

$Error.Clear()
Write-Host ('$? before is: ' + $?)
New-Error
Write-Host ('$? after is: ' + $?)
```

Output:

```
$? before is: True

New-Error : 
At C:\...\....ps1:14 char:10
+ New-Error <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [New-Error], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : New-Error

$? after is: False
```

Comment: Andy, that half answers my question. How do I get an error on the pipeline? Do I need to throw an exception? If so I take it returning an object is impossible.

Comment: @JustinDearing Using I provided an example how using a script cmdlet.

Comment: If you look at the "Error Methods" and "Write Methods" sections of the PowerShell help entry for "about_Functions_Advanced_Methods" (by using `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced_Methods` in PowerShell), you can find more information about the technique that @Andy provided in his answer. In specific, the PowerShell help entry links to the following useful MSDN article: [PSCmdlet.WriteError Method](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=142157). I mention this simply because I found MSDN's explanation of the `$PSCmdlet.WriteError` function to be helpful when reading this answer.

Comment: Great solution; is there way to suppress the output from the `$PSCmdlet.WriteError($MyErrorRecord)` call inside the function itself? In other words: can you effectively set `$?` *silently*?